# Searching and sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting, search, bubble-sort

I am trying to solve this following question in Java for practice as I am a beginner and trying to strengthen my Java skills. Here is the question...

---

According to our suggested 16 week course schedule, this programming project
should be completed no later than the Monday of Week 13. It is worth 8 per cent of
your final grade. Please refer to your Assignment Instructions document on your
Home Page for details on the submission of your work. Your overall course
assessment information is found in your Course Guide.

1. The Shell sort is a variation of the bubble sort. Instead of comparing adjacent
   values, the Shell sort adapts a concept from the binary search to determine a
   ‘gap’ across which values are compared before any swap takes place. In the
   first pass, the gap is half the size of the array. For each subsequent pass, the
   gap size is cut in half. For the final pass(es), the gap size is 1, so it would be
   the same as a bubble sort. The passes continue until no swaps occur.
   Below is the same set of values as per the bubble sort example in Chapter 18
   (p.681), showing the first pass:

9 6 8 12 3 1 7 ‐‐ size of array is 7, so gap would be 3

9 6 8 12 3 1 7 ‐‐ 9 and 12 are already in order, so no
^---------^

9 6 8 12 3 1 7 ‐‐ 6 and 3 are not in order, so swap
 ^---------^

9 3 8 12 6 1 7 ‐‐ 8 and 1 are not in order, so swap
 ^---------^

9 3 1 12 6 8 7 ‐‐ 12 and 7 are not in order, so swap
 ^---------^

9 3 8 7 6 1 12 ‐‐ end of pass 1

---

I don't want anyone to give me the direct code but would appreciate a opinion on how to tackle the question as I am having a hard time getting it started. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner so know really advanced methods!

Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you write a part of the code that would implement the first pass as shown in your question?

Comment: Check out point 3 in [StackOverflow's "What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You need to include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "I would appreciate a opinion on how to tackle the question"

First, read the Wikipedia articles on Bubble Sort and Shell Sort so that you understand what they are doing.  Or review *"the bubble sort example in Chapter 18 (p.681)"* ....

Then re-read the assignment, and see if you understand what it is saying.

The key to implementing something like this is that you first need to **understand** the algorithm.